# Reading url passed data in node.js routes

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, post, routes

I'm passing a data of a variable in URl from an python as

```
response = urlopen("localhost:5000/warehouse?fruitid=103456",timeout=10);
data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'));
```

And it reading the response in json format for further processing.

How can I write the node.js routing for posting the data which reads the passed variable value of fruitid=103456 and insert the timestamp into the database when this request occurs.

Please help me out__...

Answer (score 0):

try this - i use this to parse out json responses from other sources...

```
import pandas as pd
data1=dict(field1=data['field1_in_response'], field2=data['field2_in_response'],...);
data1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(data1)
```

Comment: The aim here is not to parse the json. I need a way to read url passed data and make the insertion to database using node.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could handle this kind of request in an Express/MongoDB app:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get('/warehouse', (req, res) => {
    console.log('fruitid:', req.query.fruitid);
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const db = client.db('mydatabase');
        db.collection('fruits').find({ id: req.query.fruitid }).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(result);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm getting the fruitid in the console. So I can call a function at the result by passing "req.query.fruitid" as an argument in that, right?

Comment: Exactly. When working with databases, you'd typically make a query for some data (for example using [MongoDB](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mongodb)), and in a callback you would then use `res.json()` or a similar method to send some data back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
var mysql = require('mysql')
var squel = require("squel");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'toor',
    database: 'invoice'
});

app.get('/warehouse', (req, res) => {
  let fruitid = req.query.fruitid;
  let queryDashboard = "select * from fruit where fruitid ='"+fruitid +"'";

    connection.query(queryDashboard, function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) throw err

        console.log('query get successful');
        var result = rows.map(data => data.name);
        res.send(result);

        // connection.end()
    })

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));`enter code here`
```

Comment: Glad to hear that

Comment: by the way since it works fine, mark the answer as correct so that others can use the same.Thanks in advance